# Каким способом правильно закрывать соединение с mysql PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

```html
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

1) **$conn->close();**

2) **mysqli_close($conn);**

2) **$conn = null;**

Comment: Первый вариант.

Comment: Это точно ? Я в недоумении

Comment: Я впервые задаюсь таким вопросом (никогда не работал с PDO напрямую), но да, обязанность закрывать за собой ресурсы лежит на разработчике. mysqli_close вообще никакого отношения здесь не имеет.

Comment: еще вопрос, а зачем тебе их вообще закрывать? если ты сервер (упаси боже) пишешь, они переиспользуются, если ты веб пишешь, они закрываются с концом скрипта. если у тебя скрипт, который коннектится к МИЛЛИОНУ БД, то у тебя интересная ситуация, расскажи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Странные у вас варианты ответов. Метода `close` у PDO нет в принципе, при чём тут `mysqli_close` непонятно.

[В документации](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) ответ дан и довольно недвусмысленно:

> To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring
>   that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by
>   assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do
>   this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your
>   script ends.

Удалите все ссылки на объект PDO и он закроет соединение. Можете присвоить `NULL`, можете сделать `unset`.